# How to fill input text from another autocomplete Rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-autocomplete

I have a form with a task(uses Rails4 autocomplete gem) and a project text_field. I want to be able to fill it just from selecting a task.

So if I have

- task1 : project1

When I type *'ta'*, and select *task1* from the autocomplete, I want the *project* field to be filled with the correspondent project (*project1* in this case).

This is the form:

```
<%= form_for :instance, url: instances_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :task_name %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :task_name,   autocomplete_task_name_static_pages_path %>
  <%= f.text_field :project_name %>
<% end %>
```

And this is the controller:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :task, :name
end
```

Reading the [documentation](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete) I've tried adding :

```
:display_value => :task_full_info
```

and

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :project

  def task_full_info
    self.project.name
  end
end
```

But that doesn't work. What's the proper way of doing it on Rails 4 with the rails4-autocomplete gem? Also, what changes should I make if I change the project text_field to a dropdownlist?

EDIT:
Server log:

```
Started GET "/static_pages/autocomplete_task_name?term=do" for ... at 2016-05-05 18:05:50 -0300
Processing by StaticPagesController#autocomplete_task_name as JSON
  Parameters: {"term"=>"do"}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Task Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "tasks"."id" as id, "tasks"."name" as name, "project_name", "tasks"."project_id" FROM "tasks" WHERE (LOWER(name) LIKE 'do%')  ORDER BY LOWER(name) ASC LIMIT 10
  Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

Comment: was my post helpful at all?

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't work on my project until now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation you linked, I see [here](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete#user-content-getting-extra-object-data) what you want to do with `:project_name`. So your code would look something like:

```
<%= form_for :instance, url: instances_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :task_name %>
  <%= f.autocomplete_field :task_name, autocomplete_task_name_static_pages_path, :update_elements => {:project_name => '#instance_project_name'} %>
  <%= f.text_field :project_name %>
<% end %>
```

I'm assuming here that **instance_project_name** is the actual id of the `:project_name` text field (it should if the code is as you stated).

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :task, :name, :extra_data => [:project_id, :project_name]
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :project

  delegate :name, to: :project, prefix: true
end
```

I'd also recommend you to change your gem to [this one](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete), since it's linked from the documentation and seems to be more updated than the one you are using.

**Update**:

As it turns out, the gem does the following when autocomplete triggers:

1) Makes an **Activerecord** `select` given the autocomplete field and what's given on the `extra_data` option. So that's why the weird `"project_name"` in the `Task` query from your log.

2) Then it takes that **Activerecord** result and uses the `send` method for each requested field (again, the autocomplete field and the ones specified on `extra_data`).

That's why whenever you need a field from a joined table, as a workaround, it's **required** that you put on extra data the foreing_key, since otherwise **1)** won't have access to that foreign key and when **2)** it's executed it won't find the association.

I guess the gem could be improved by always selecting all foreign keys in **1)** query but for now you'll have to settle with the workaround.

Comment: Auto-complete stops working after I add :extra_data => [:project_name]. What I am doing wrong (I already change to your suggested gem)

Comment: Have you also added the `update_elements` code on the view?

Comment: However, it works if I change :project_name for :name or :id. It even works if I call a function which returns those parameters, but not self.project.name or self.project_name, for example.

Comment: Is the server throwing any exception on the ajax call? maybe you don't have a project linked to that task?

Comment: I've added the server log :)
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :tasks, dependent: :destroy

Comment: It works now, I just added project_id on :extra_data => [:project_name, :project_id]. I think the problem was javascript didn't have the project_id to make the proper query.

Comment: @Gaston are you sure? From the log you sent me JS is not doing the query, the server is, and it clearly says what I told you: `Module::DelegationError (Task#project_name delegated to project.name, but project is nil: #<Task id: 7, name: "enim">)` - meaning, server couldn't find a project linked to the task with id 7.

Comment: Both project and task are linked (has_many, belongs_to) and exist a project with the task's project_id. Now the code works. is there something wrong with the query?(I've updated the server log)

Comment: I've updated the answer given your log and your comments, I've made a little research on the gem's code - it didn't make sense at all, but I guess it's just that the gem is not very polished.

Comment: btw @Gaston if the answer was of any help please give positive feedback, and if you think it has the right answer now also mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: Yes you've been really helpful. Thanks for the update :D